# Email Sending over Distributed System?

Tags: email-server, email

Guys I am wondering if it is possible to setup "Mail Server" (like MailEnable) over different servers so that the load is distributed equally on all servers ?

For example : 
I am sending 100 emails from domain example.com, so I want this to be distributed among 10 servers (each server having its own dedicated IP), so that each server has to send only 10 emails only.

How would this be possible ? any pointers please?

Comment: Most spammers handle this with botnets.  Is that what you need?  A spam botnet?

Comment: slap a load balancer in front of it and have it distribute traffic?

Comment: Nope, I don't need a botnet and neither I am spamming. Currently, our organization has one mail server (using mailenable) and it takes a lot of time to send email to all the subscribers who have subscribed to our newsletter so basically I want to send email using multiple servers at once.

Comment: On modern hardware, unless you have huge lists, the bottlenecks are often the recipients rate-limiting requests. Proper tuning of the system and completing the bulk mailing requests at problematic IPs can impact things significantly.  Also you may want to read the docs as it specially addresses clustering. https://www.mailenable.com/support/MEEICG.pdf

Answer (score 3):

Yes,   you can set up a separate SMTP mail server on separate machines.  Many bulk mail programs have the option to distribute mail to each individual server.

If the goal is to have separate IP addresses,  you can set up virtual box to have the updates sent with the same IP address.

There is nothing extra you have to do than configure the mail servers. SMTP was designed to work with multiple servers.

If you are having problems with delivery at the receiver, you will probably be banned quickly from most major mail providers.  Your ISP will probably shut you down unless you find an unscrupulous provider.  Mail providers look for this type of pattern related to spam.  If you are having difficulty getting mail delivered, I would suggest checking your content and reaching out directly to the mail providers.  You can get white-listed, oftentimes with a review of your TOS and Privacy policies.  Also, separate your business function correspondence and your marketing to separate servers.   Marketing servers always get a higher block rate, because spam is in the eye of the beholder and spam history is kept by IP address.

In the end, it's all about your product, services and how you acquire your list.  Marketing stuff to people who don't want it will get your IP banned, no matter how many you have.  (Even on the botnets)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I see so it is possible to setup my SMTP server on separate machines. That is good, however I was wondering how does these email giants like google, yahoo etc distribute their load? Do they use the same methods?

Comment: @NewbieProgrammer - A lot of the methods that the mail giants use are secret, because they do not want people to game the system. The infrastructures are mostly cloud based and the server software is custom or heavily modified stock software. Load balancing and multiple servers are employed.   They have much more complicated needs though.   For the most part, you have control over what is sent and received in a newsletter format. The mail giants do not have source material control, only filtering, so the problem sets are fundamentally different past a certain level.

Comment: I see Edward, so what do you think I should do ? Basically I need to cut the cost to minimum. We already have multiple servers that we use for hosting etc so getting multiple servers is not an issue for me, however using email marketing services like mailchimp is very costly per month (upon my scale). Which mail server do you recommend ?

Comment: I would recommend using whatever you are comfortable with. Just spin up whatever comes with your distro.  If you have time to burn and are experienced with patching and building software, qmail is probably my choice, but my memory is that its not straightforward.